# Adding to an arraylist with an event listener [Java]

Tags: java, arraylist, event-listener

I have a gameloop with a triangle that moves around the screen randomly. I want to add a button that when clicked will add another randomly moving triangle. I'm using event listeners and no matter where I place it I'm still getting an exception

Here's my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import drawing.Canvas;
import tools.Utils;
import triangle.DynamicTriangle;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TriangleProgram {
    private JFrame frame; 
    private Canvas canvas; 
    private JPanel lowerPanel; 
    private JButton addTriangleButton; 
    private ArrayList<DynamicTriangle> triangles;

    public void gameLoop() {
        int deltaTime = 20;

        triangles.add(new RandomTriangleA(canvas, 150, 150));

        for (DynamicTriangle dynamicTriangle : triangles) {
            dynamicTriangle.drawTriangle();
        }
        while (true)
        {
            for (DynamicTriangle dynamicTriangle : triangles) {
                dynamicTriangle.undrawTriangle();
            }

            for (DynamicTriangle dynamicTriangle : triangles) {
                dynamicTriangle.update(100);
                dynamicTriangle.wrapPosition();
            }

            for (DynamicTriangle dynamicTriangle : triangles) {
                dynamicTriangle.drawTriangle();
            }

            Utils.pause(deltaTime);
            canvas.repaint();
        }

    }

    public TriangleProgram() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Canvas");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        canvas = new Canvas();
        frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        lowerPanel = new JPanel();
        lowerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        triangles = new ArrayList<DynamicTriangle>();

        addTriangleButton = new JButton("Add Triangle"); 
        lowerPanel.add(addTriangleButton);
        frame.revalidate();

        addTriangleButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        gameLoop();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running TriangleProgram...");
        new TriangleProgram();
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.println(triangles.size());
            triangles.add(new RandomTriangleA(canvas, 150, 150));
        }

    }

}
```

I expect every time I press the button that a new triangle is added to the canvas, but instead I get the stack trace:

```
Running TriangleProgram...
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out-of-bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:517)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedList.remove(Collections.java:2424)
    at drawing.Canvas.removeMostRecentLine(Canvas.java:162)
    at triangle.Triangle.undrawTriangle(Triangle.java:131)
    at TriangleProgram.gameLoop(TriangleProgram.java:29)
    at TriangleProgram.<init>(TriangleProgram.java:69)
    at TriangleProgram.main(TriangleProgram.java:75)
```

Comment: When you ask about an exception, **always** post the complete exception stack trace. It tells what and where the problem is.

Comment: Hi, you seem to be referencing triangle near the top of your 'gameLoop' method, but the variable is never declared.

Comment: @JamesMacca It's initialized in the constructor.

Comment: @JamesMacca check constructor

Comment: @BakonJarser 'trianges' is initialised in the constructor. 'triangle' is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
        triangle.add(new Triangle(canvas, 150, 150));
```

Well here you never even declare `triangle` so not sure how this code even runs to give you an exception. I'm assuming you meant `triangles`
Also you can probably(?) condense your loops.

Edit: Also when you declare the list triangles, why is it a list of `DynamicTriangle` but when you initialize and add to list it's `Triangle`.

Not sure if `DynamicTriangle` is subclass of `Triangle` or just typo but if that's the case it shouldn't compile.

If it's a typo then make your `ArrayList<DynamicTriangle> triangles` use `Triangle` instead.

If `DyanmicTriangle` is a subclass of `Triangle` then you want to declare and initialize triangles as `ArrayList<Triangle>()` and when you add you do `.add(new DynamicTriangle(...`

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder I don't mean they have an issue with them but he can probably just use one for each loop in the while loop instead of three. depends on what hes trying to achieve and what those methods he's calling actually does.

Comment: this was my mistake, I was renaming my code be more sensibly named before I posted and made a few errors. I've updated the code in the main post along with the full stack trace.

Comment: @ExitEnter the problem isnt in the class you posted. can you post undrawTriangle and removeMostRecentLine